# When i run the code, even if i type in a film on the list, it says that its not there and fails.What do i do?

Tags: python

```
def FilmSelection():
    list1=["The Magnificent Seven",'Wreck It Ralph','James Bond','Now you see me 2','Captain America:The Winter Soldier']
    choice=input("what film would you like to watch?")
    while choice!=str(list1[1:5]):
        print("sorry, that film is not available right now")
        choiceb=input("would you like to select a different film?")
        if choiceb=="yes"or choiceb=="Yes":
            print("that's fine")
            choice=input("what film would you like to watch?")
        else:
            print("have a nice day")
            sys.exit()
    else:
        print("lets get to times!")
```

Comment: why don't you do some basic debugging, like seeing what `str(list1[1:5])` produces, and see if you can figure out why `choice != str(...)` isn't working...

Comment: i will thanks, sorry i'm quite new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` condition will not match when the user inputs one of the film names.
Instead, use this:

```
while choice not in list1:
```

This will find if `choice` is `in` `list1`.
Also, instead of using `else`, you should do this:

```
while choice not in list1:
    # ...
print('Let’s go to times!')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! :) Much appreciated friend